# Kafka - Difference between Events with batch data and Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, event-driven-design

What is the fundamental difference between an event with a batch of data attached and a kafka stream that occasionally sends data ? Can they be used interchangeably ? When should I use the first and when the latter ? Could you provide some simple use cases ?

Note: There is some info in the **comments** of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014975/kafka-consumer-api-vs-streams-api) but I would ask for a more well rounded answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that with "difference" between streams and events with batched data you are thinking of:

- Stream: Every event of interest is sent immediately to the stream. Those *individual* events are therefore fine-grained, small(er) in size.
- Events with data batch: Multiple *individual* events get aggregated into a larger batch, and when the batch reaches a certain size, a certain time has passed, or a business transaction has completed, the batch event is sent to the stream. Those *batch* events are therefore more coarse-grained and large(r) in size.

Here is a list of characteristics that I can think of:

- Realtime/latency: End-to-end processing time will typically be smaller for *individual* events, and longer for *batch* events, because the publisher may wait with sending *batch* events until enough *individual* events have accumulated.
- Throughput: Message brokers differ in performance characteristics regarding max. # of in/out events / sec at comparable in/out amounts of data. For example, comparing Kinesis vs. Kafka, Kinesis has a lower max. # of in/out events / sec it can handle than a finely tuned Kafka cluster. So if you were to use Kinesis, *batch* events may make more sense to achieve the desired throughput in terms of # of *individual* events. Note: From what I know, the Kinesis client library has a feature to transparently batch *individual* events if desired/possible to increase throughput.
- Order and correlation: If multiple *individual* events belong to one business transaction and need to be processed by consumers together and/or possibly in order, then *batch* events may make this task easier because all related data becomes available to consumers at once. With *individual* events, you would have to put appropriate measures in place like selecting appropriate partition keys to guarantee that *individual* events get processed in order and possibly by the same consumer worker instance.
- Failure case: If *batch* events contain independent *individual* events, then it may happen that a subset of *individual* events in a batch fails to process (irrelevant whether temporary or permanent failure). In such a case, consumers may not be able to simply retry the entire event because parts of the *batch* event has already caused state changes. Explicit logic (=additional effort) may be necessary to handle partial processing failure of *batch* events.

To answer your question whether the two can be used interchangeably, I would say in theory yes, but depending on the specific use case, one of the two approaches will likely result better performance or result in less complex design/code/configuration.

I'll edit my answer if I can think of more differentiating characteristics.