# Understanding the requirements for a Kafka streams application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I do not want to go into details because this is an assignment I have been given by a company and I do not want it solved by others.

But I have a doubt. The requirements are very simple, they say something like this:
"Consume a Kafka stream of events - the application consumes the event streams, does some counting operations on it and then delivers it to a caller via REST".
It is about making a Spring Boot application which would be a microservice in a real life scenario.

It is all pretty clear to me but the way is worded makes it hard for me to understand if it's expected for me to use the Streams API or using a Kafka consumer would be enough.
There is nothing more specified but the case scenario is theoretically high load / distributed systems. Do you think Kafka consumer would be enough here, or would be considered an error?

I have tried to implkement the code both ways, and I have searched online the pros and cons of using or not the Streaming API in your environment

Comment: Kafka-streams is just Kafka with some RocksDB and auto topic creation magic thrown in, in my experience streams start out simple but you often have to spend time, peeling back the magic. If all your doing is counting it's a good fit, I've used the windowing functions successfully for that sort of thing, haven't used KTables much though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka: Consumer API vs Streams API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014975/kafka-consumer-api-vs-streams-api)